# Optimal partitioning of n-arrays

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, mathematical-programming, partitions, integer-partitions

You're given N integer arrays. Each array can have different size and contains unique values. However same integers can be found in different arrays.

The goal is to partition those arrays into K groups such that:

1. Arrays grouped together don't share any integer
2. I want to minimize the number of groups

Example:

Input: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [4, 6, 10]]

Suboptimal Solution using 3 groups:

- group 1: [[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8]]
- group 2: [[2, 4, 5]]
- group 3: [[4, 6, 10]]

Optimal Solution using 2 groups:

- group 1: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 10]]
- group 2: [[2, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]

Any idea on how to solve this effectively?

Comment: There's no polynomial time algorithm, you can quite easily reduce this to the minimum clique cover problem.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. There is a difference between `effectively` (having the effect under consideration) and *efficiently* (low effort in relation to effect and problem size).